# Efficiently drawing path in Maps With More than Thousand GeoPoints.

Tags: android, mapactivity

I am using a `MapActivity`. I take a set of GeoPoints from a webserver using JSON and parse it to decoded the Polyline code into geo-points (latitude and longitude) which are then stored in `ArrayList<Geopoints>`.

These points then get drawn on the `MapActivity`.

My problem is that it's not running efficiently since my `ArrayList<Geopoints>` size is more than 2000. How can I increase the efficiency?

Sample code what i ve done while drawing is

```
ArrayList'<'Geopoints> mGeoPoints;
```

Say size of `mGeoPoints=2000;`

In a class extended by Overlay. some methods of that class how i am writing is.

```
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,long when) {
       super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
        drawPath(mapView, canvas);
        return true;
    }

public void drawPath(MapView mv, Canvas canvas) {
        int x1 = -1, y1 = -1, x2 = -1, y2 = -1;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
                for (int i = 0; i < mGeoPoints.size(); i++) {
            Point point = new Point();
            mv.getProjection().toPixels(mGeoPoints.get(i), point);
            x2 = point.x;
            y2 = point.y;
            if (i > 0) {
                canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint);
            }
            x1 = x2;
            y1 = y2;
        }
    }
```

This code is working fine. its drawing correctly on the map. When i zoom the map or move the map application is hanging.

I have set the zoom level to 16 `mapController.setZoom(16);`; can any one help me? To make it run fast even when user zoom it by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first 2 things that really jump out at me are `i < mGeoPoints.size();` and `Point point = new Point();`

You can optimise both of these right there by storing the length of the array in a local variable and much ore importantly reuse the variable point. Creating a new instance 2000 times per draw loop will hammer your phone into tiny pieces!

Also make sure your `getProjection(...)` method reuses the point passed in. As long as your point values are reset properly you can use something like this:

```
Point point = new Point();

for (int i = 0; i < mGeoPoints.size(); i++) 
{
    mv.getProjection().toPixels(mGeoPoints.get(i), point);
    x2 = point.x;
    y2 = point.y;
    if (i > 0) 
    {
        canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a follow up, a minor improvement to squeeze a little extra out is to setup your paint in `onCreate(...)` and just access it in `onDraw(...)` the less you have to create new objects the better, especially in methods that are called a lot / in loops.